# Counting Dictionary values of each key in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi friends is their any way to count number of values for a particular key of a dictionary in django templates

like suppose i have a dict

```
  y =  { 1:('A', 'B','C'), 2:('C','D','E','F') }
```

I am passing this dict. from my django views and i want to count the number of values for each key in my django templates to perform some particular task.

i tried with count but it is not working ........any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in template filter `length` should help.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#length
The `length` filter is described thusly in [the Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter04/):

> length: Returns the length of the value. You can use this on a list or
>   a string, or any Python object that knows how to determine its length
>   (i.e., any object that has a `__len__()` method).

Example:

```
<ul>
  {% for k,v in y.items %}
    <li>key: {{ k }} has {{ v|length }} value(s)</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```